# Does my water heater's sacrificial anode appear to need replacing?

Tags: water-heater, anode

The anode in the my water heater is around 4 years old. I took it out for the first time. I am not sure why does it look like having a black coating instead of a metallic color. Does it looks like need replacing?

[image]

PS: My heater has been buckled to the wall with its installation, which made it easy for me (Don't need another person to hold the heater or find something to fix the heater in place) to loosen it with a 1/2 inch Breaker bar + ratchet + a **4 feet long pipe**.

Comment: You have it out, this is the perfect time to replace it.  They aren't that expensive.

Answer (score 5):

The eroded part is it doing its "sacrificial" job; it will eventually erode away to nothing, but will probably fall apart or become otherwise un-removable before then. I would go ahead and put in a new one now while you still can. You've already done the hard part in getting the old one out, and replacements are not too expensive.

Screencap of useful [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/2IUNIUZz4Os) on replacing water heater sacrificial anode rod:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

that rod has at least a couple more years of service left.  It will crud up thicker, but the crud is soft, and it will either break off and fall to the bottom, or scrape off when you pull it out.  Where you have to flush it out by the tank drain.  Note a typical small drain could plug up with crud, then you might have to back-flush it to clear.

If there is no bare support wire showing yet then there is NO reason to replace the anode that is still doing its job.  I don't replace unless at least 6 inches of wire is showing.